# multi-section UITableView issues

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an UITableView that contains 3 NSArrays and 3 NSDictionaries for each array.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    contentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    self.settingsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Settings", nil];
    NSDictionary *settingsDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:settingsArray forKey:@"Settings"];

    self.infoArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Version 1.0", @"© Copyrights 2010", @"Developer Site", @"App Page", @"Report a Bug", nil];
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:infoArray forKey:@"Settings"];

    self.contactArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Developer Site", @"App Page", @"Report a Bug", nil];
    NSDictionary *contactDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:contactArray forKey:@"Settings"];

    [contentArray addObject:infoDict];
    [contentArray addObject:settingsDict];
    [contentArray addObject:contactDict];
    }
```

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    if ([[infoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Version 1.1"]) {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }

    if ([[infoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"© Copyrights 2010"]) {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }

    if ([[settingsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Settings"]) {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"NULL" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    if ([[contactArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Developer Site"]) {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }

    if ([[contactArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"App Page"]) {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }

    if ([[contactArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Report a Bug"]) {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];      
    }
}
```

The problem is when I'm trying to select a row, the application is crashing

Thanks

Comment: What error message is logged?

Comment: 2010-07-25 21:58:19.355 Dual Search[48109:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (4) beyond bounds (1)'
2010-07-25 21:58:19.355 Dual Search[48109:207] Stack: (
    43292752,
    44450604,
    43030283,
    43030122,
    748457,
    187239,
    49603,
    3416117,
    3375658,
    330631,
    42571740,
    42567848,
    51927197,
    51927394,
    3056498,
    9476,
    9330
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error will occur when you attempt to access an index beyond the bounds of an array.  For example, you'll encounter an NSRangeException if your array has only one item and you ask for the object at index 3.  The immediate solution is to check the array's size before querying its contents.

```
NSArray* exampleArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil];
int items = [exampleArray count];
if(indexPath.row < items) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have multiple arrays.
Array for each section.

Comment: Yes, but you're trying to access all three in didSelectRow.

Comment: I tried it and still crashing.
I did I little check and all of the objects no matter in which array goes to the last index of the third array